# Prove that non-null zero-diagonal symmetric matrices must have at least one nonzero eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

Consider a real zero-diagonal symmetric matrix, that is, a symmetric matrix with only zeros on the main diagonal. Assuming that the matrix is non-null, how do we prove that it must have at least one nonzero eigenvalue?

I guess one possible approach would be to find the characteristic polynomial and consider roots, but I feel like there is a neater approach or idea that I am missing.

I also know that the sum of the eigenvalues must be zero, but that doesn't seem to lead me anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any symmetric matrix is normal and therefore has eigen-decomposition $U\Lambda U^T$ with $\Lambda$ the matrix containing the eigen-values on its diagonal, if $\Lambda=0$ this your original matrix has to be $0$, which is false in your case.